# F# Define function to act as delegate to .net Action

Tags: f#, delegates

in System.Activities.WorkflowApplication there is a delegate property:

```
        public Action<WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs> Completed { get; set; }
```

In my program so far, I have a variable that is an instance of this class

I want to define an F# function to set that:

```
let f (e: WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs) = 
    // body
myInst.Completed <- f
```

but this produces the error:

> Error 102 This expression was expected to have type
>       Action     but here has type
>       'a -> unit

how do I complete function "f" to satisfy the compiler?

Comment: `let f = System.Action<WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs>(fun e -> (*body to unit*))`

Comment: Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 18):

If you pass an anonymous function `fun a -> ...` to a method or a constructor that expects a `System.Action<...>` or a `System.Func<...>`, then it is automatically converted; in any other case, you need to convert it explicitly like @Funk indicated.

```
let f = System.Action<WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs>(fun e ->
    // body
)
myInst.Completed <- f

// Another solution:

let f (e: WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs) = 
    // body
myInst.Completed <- System.Action<_>(f)
```

Comment: that last one is a new form to me.  What does the underscore represent here?

Comment: It lets the type inference system guess the type. Based on the type of `f`, it can deduce what type the `Action`'s parameter is. I could just as well have written `Action<WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs>`, but this is shorter and just as clear.